# Angular ng-repeat orderBy not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Hi I have data pulled from the YouTube api that displays channel info. Here is an example of the JSON

```
channels: {
    UCxxxxxxxxxxx: {
        channelId: "xxxx",
        channelTitle: "xxxx",
        description: "xxxx",
        channelId: "xxxx",
        title: "xxxx"
    },
    UCxxxxxxxxxxx: {
        channelId: "xxxx",
        channelTitle: "xxxx",
        description: "xxxx",
        channelId: "xxxx",
        title: "xxxx"
    }
}
```

I have passed the `channels` object to `$scope.results`

I just copied the example from the angular docs like so inside the controller

```
    $scope.predicate = 'title';
    $scope.reverse = true;
    $scope.order = function(predicate) {
        $scope.reverse = ($scope.predicate === predicate) ? !$scope.reverse : false;
        $scope.predicate = predicate;
    };
```

And here is the html markup

```
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <a href="" ng-click="order('title')">Name</a>
                    <span class="sortorder" ng-show="predicate === 'title'" ng-class="{reverse:reverse}"></span>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <a href="" ng-click="order('channelTitle')">Channel</a>
                    <span class="sortorder" ng-show="predicate === 'channelTitle'" ng-class="{reverse:reverse}"></span>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <a href="" ng-click="order('viewCount')">Views</a>
                    <span class="sortorder" ng-show="predicate === 'viewCount'" ng-class="{reverse:reverse}"></span>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <a href="" ng-click="order('subscriberCount')">Subscribers</a>
                    <span class="sortorder" ng-show="predicate === 'subscriberCount'" ng-class="{reverse:reverse}"></span>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="result in results | orderBy:predicate:reverse">
                    <td ng-bind="result.title"></td>
                    <td>
                        <a ng-show="result.channelTitle" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/{{result.channelId}}" ng-bind="result.channelTitle"></a>
                        <div ng-show="!result.channelTitle" ng-bind="'--'"><div>
                    </td>
                    <td ng-bind="result.info.viewCount | number"></td>
                    <td ng-bind="result.info.subscriberCount | number"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

When I click the table header, there is no error. So I can't exactly figure out what's not working. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your object (used in ng-repeat) is different from original example (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy).

```
channels: {
    UCxxxxxxxxxxx: {
        channelId: "xxxx",
        channelTitle: "xxxx",
        description: "xxxx",
        channelId: "xxxx",
        title: "xxxx"
    },
    UCxxxxxxxxxxx: {
        channelId: "xxxx",
        channelTitle: "xxxx",
        description: "xxxx",
        channelId: "xxxx",
        title: "xxxx"
    }
}
```

Result must be array.
Original data:

```
$scope.friends =
          [{name:'John', phone:'555-1212', age:10},
           {name:'Mary', phone:'555-9876', age:19},
           {name:'Mike', phone:'555-4321', age:21},
           {name:'Adam', phone:'555-5678', age:35},
           {name:'Julie', phone:'555-8765', age:29}];
```